# Create new vsftpd user and lock to (specify) home / login directory

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, vsftpd

I need to periodically give temporary and limited access to various directories on a CentOS linux server that has vsftp installed.

I've created a user using `useradd [user_name]` and given them a password using `passwd [password]`.

I've created a directory in `/var/ftp` and then I bind this to the directory that I wish to limit access to.

What else do I need to specifically do to ensure that when this user logs into FTP, they only have access to this directory please?

Comment: Sorry but have you ever considered to check vsftpd.conf?

Comment: Yes. I have. It doesn't tell me how to instruct a specific user to log in to a specific directory...?

Comment: Sure? chroot_list_enable option... Or you mean to override directory different than $HOME?

Comment: I want to know how to declare a specific home directory for a specific user. I've enabled `chroot_list_enable` and created `/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list`. I just didn't know what to do next.

Comment: Then usermod to change user's homedir.

Comment: Like this? `usermod -d /var/ftp/blah/ username`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Complete answer that solved my question for any others that are after a step by step walkthrough...

Install `vsftpd` using [this as a guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-centos-6--2).

- Create user with `useradd [user_name]`.
- Create user's password with `passwd [user_name]`. (You'll be prompted to specify the password).
- Create FTP directory in `/var/ftp` and then bind to the 'home' directory you wish to specify for this user with `mount --bind /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/ /var/ftp/custom_name/`.
- Change user's home directory with `usermod -d /var/ftp/custom_name/ user_name`

  In `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`, ensure all all of the following are set:-

  - chroot_local_user=YES
  - chroot_list_enable=YES
  - chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

Only list users in the `vsftpd.chroot_list` file if you want them to have full access to anywhere on the server. By not listing them in this file, you're saying restrict all `vsftpd` users to their specified home directory.

In other words (for reference):-

1. means that by default, ALL users get chrooted except users in the file...

   - chroot_local_user=YES
   - chroot_list_enable=YES
2. means that by default, ONLY users in the file get chrooted...

   - chroot_local_user=NO
   - chroot_list_enable=YES

Comment: Why not setting the home directory of that user directly to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/`? Is there some problem with that (like any potential risks)?

Comment: I just found out that vsftp seems to forbid to grant an ftp user write permissions on the chroot top level for security reasons (but I'm not 100% sure). So that might be a reason to have this "indirection" in order to grant the ftp user write access to a specific folder while not allowing to view *any sibling* folder (which would be the case if you simply set his home one level up, which avoids the mentioned issue). (see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072383&p=12303279#post12303279)

Comment: @zigojacko does your user only see their assigned home dir? For me, this _defaults_ the user to the assigned directory, but, they still can see other folders and can snoop around all the way up to root, though with only read access.

Comment: This answer, in combination with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208960/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-one-folder-and-not-allow-them-to-move-out-his-folder was the full answer for me.  I ended up creating a user in a group and limited the group access to the desired directory.

Comment: If you use "mount" you do it only once if I'm correct? An entry in /etc/fstab would be better I think?

Answer (score 14):

For me it didn't work even after the above. There was a local_root already set to a directory, and whatever I do, user's directory hasn't jailed.
Finally it is worked after only changed

> chroot_local_user=YES

And following procedure

> 1. vi /etc/vsftpd.conf
> 2. Add the line 'user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf' (no quotes)
> 3. mkdir /etc/vsftpd_user_conf;
> 4. cd /etc/vsftpd_user_conf
> 5. vi user_name;
> 6. Enter the line 'local_root=/srv/ftp/user_name'

Just my two cents if anyone else had same issue.

Comment: I followed this procedure to change the root directory of vsftpd, including the additional steps by gnaanaa.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work yet. Filezilla reports 530 Login incorrect. The user and password are according to the procedure above (user_name). I created a test user ftp2, and set its password. The Filezilla normal logon uses that username and password.

I also set the root directory read only, and created a lower level directory with write permissions according to this post

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 if that makes any difference, @gnaanaa. Also I thought it was odd that there was no ftp directory in /var. So I had to create /var/ftp, and then /var/ftp/user_name.
`code`<br/>
    Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)<br/>
    Command:    USER ftp2<br/>
    Response:   331 Please specify the password.<br/>
    Command:    PASS *****<br/>   
    Response:   530 Login incorrect.<br/>
    Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server <br/> `code`

Comment: Firstly, look why you couldn't login to the server. You can debug the issue with jailing only after success login. Cheers.

Comment: Does vsftp use a different user/password compared to the accounts on the machine?  I discovered that smb passwords had to be set separately with smbpasswd -a.  Does vsftpd work the same way?

Comment: No, it is the system user account. check this answer : http://askubuntu.com/questions/413677/vsftpd-530-login-incorrect

Comment: Not working either

Comment: It worked for me after I changed the owner of the folder vsftpd_user_conf and user_name files in it to the vsftpd service account user (think it is root:root by default).

Answer (score 0):

what if you want everyone to have chroot but a different landing folder within that chroot?

```
local_root=/folder
home_folder=$local_root/$USER
```

Is this not reasonable ?

Answer (score -1):

The chrooting mentioned in previous answers didn't work on my ubuntu 18.04 server.
I finally got it working using this reference: https://passingcuriosity.com/2014/openssh-restrict-to-sftp-chroot/